# iPhone: How to Get Basic Authentication to HTTPS Web Service Using NSURLCredential

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

I am trying to call an https web service (RESTful) using basic authentication.
It works fine if I put the credentials in the url itself but I would rather add it to the request so that the password does not appear, for instance in an exception.

I am using the following code:

```
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myuser"
                                                             password:@"mypassword"
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                             initWithHost:@"example.com"
                                             port:443
                                             protocol:@"https"
                                             realm:nil
                                             authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];


    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]  setDefaultCredential:credential
                                                        forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection  connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

but it does not work. The `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate method gets called and I can add a credential there but ideally I would send it with the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the credentials in the header if it is basic authentication. Works for me every time.

For sending the username and password in the header of the request

```
NSString *authString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *finalAuth = base64 of authString;
```

In your request, add a header with the field name **Authorization** and value `"Basic " + finalAuth`

Comment: I tried this before, but couldn't get it to work. I'll give it another go.

Comment: Does it give you an error? Are you sure the error is because of failing the authentication challenge?

Comment: This worked for me, odd there's no mention of it in the Apple docs. Also I had to roll my own Base64 encoding which is horrible.

Comment: What's the `base64 of authString` part?

Answer (score 0):

I missed that last line of code where you are using NSURLConnection. Make sure that your delegate is responding to :

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
```

And is returning YES for your protectionSpace.

Also, make sure that your delegate is responding to :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

Here you can assign the credential that you created to the `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` in the proposedCredential property, as well as your `NSURLProtectionSpace` instance into the protectionSpace property of the `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`.

Comment: It works fine when  it get the challenge back, but I am trying to avoid that round trip by sending the credentials with the initial request.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a round trip. Either way, the connection will be challenged and it will have to provide credentials.